# How to hide my sql source code using sybase ase?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sap-ase

**I have 3 SPs that do a validation** regarding some input and output tables.

> They check if none of the data was changed.

---

I don't want to anyone see how the validation is made.

**So, how can I *hide* this SPs code?**

Comment: **From** whom? What access do "they" have to the code? To the server?

Comment: @Piskvor from client that has access to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the [**sp_hidetext**](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sprocs/html/sprocs/sprocs147.htm) :)

> Hides the source text for the specified compiled object. Hides the
>   text of computed columns and function-based index keys.

**It isn't reversible so save the code before using it!**